# 12.04 LTS Installation Process Suddenly Stops

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot, windows-7, partitioning

I plan to install Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS alongside Windows 7 in Asus A43E Series and I had an unsuccessful experience about the installation.

Here is the chronology:

1. I installed Ubuntu via USB Stick. While the 3 options appear, I select the 1st which is "install inside Windows 7", but the process suddenly stopped. The next instruction was to *remove the installation media and press the "enter"* button which I did, but Windows 7 appeared not Ubuntu.
2. Then I try another media, the DVD instead of the USB Stick and I had the same result.

Please help.

Comment: Try doing an [MD5SUM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) on the ISO file, that will verify the file

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Wubi (Ubuntu INSIDE Windows), install Ubuntu the standard way (in its own partition). See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall

Your disk may be GPT, and Wubi is not compatible with GPT.